# Align description item's paragraph with edge of body?

Tags: enumitem

I've got the label (foo) just where I want it to be. Now I'd like the paragraph (Lorem...) to align with the edge of the body. How?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{erwlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[erwlist]
{align=right,
%  leftmargin=*,
%  itemindent=*,
%  labelsep=*,
  labelindent=-1pt,
%  itemsep=0pt,
  font=\sffamily\tiny }

\begin{document}

\begin{erwlist}
\item[foo] \lipsum[1][1]
\end{erwlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  `labelsep=1pt`from following figure

[image]

and

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{erwlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[erwlist]
{align=right,
 labelsep=1pt,%<--------------------added
  labelindent=-1pt,
  font=\sffamily\tiny }

\begin{document}

\begin{erwlist}
\item[foo] \lipsum[1][1]
\end{erwlist}

\end{document}
```